# Can I apply Ambari on a Running cluster?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I was looking for how to monitor Hadoop clusters more conveniently, and then I came across something called Ambari.

I want to apply Apache Ambari to my running Hadoop cluster.
Is it possible to apply Apache Ambari to a running Hadoop cluster?
If this is not possible, are there any future patches planned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Coldbrew   No.  Ambari should be installed on a fresh cluster.  If you indeed need to use ambari hadoop, I would recommend make a new ambari cluster w/ hadoop configured as close to possible as your existing hadoop and then migrating the native hadoop data to the new platform.